# Can't use scroll on left menu

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, menu, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have an issue with my left menu. On a normal screen it's fine, the menu items are all there. But on smaller screen it cuts out the last items and I can't get it to have a horizontal scroll.
I have tried to replicate the problem using a JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Bettleb45/g7004ngm/1/

I have tried several ways like `overflow-x : auto`, `position: sticky;` and more that was suggested on other sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to solve this you should add the following to `#sidebar`:

```
  #sidebar {
    overflow: auto;
  }
```

Check updated working [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/henser/g7004ngm/3/)